# How to Fix Object not found in the following code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up a new macro to assign comments on a range of Cells with information from another range of cells. I Keep getting an

> "Object Required" error.

I ran the code on a more simple workbook and it worked great. When I adapted for new column, sheet, row names and different ranges I ran into the error.

```
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim strComment As String, strConsolidated As String, strPERSON As String, strConcat As String
    Dim arrConcat() As String
    Dim lngPos As Long
    Dim WIPDATA As Worksheet
    Dim Display As Worksheet
    Set WIPDATA = Worksheets("WIPDATA")
    Set Display = Worksheets("Display")


    For Each rngCell In WIPDATA.Range("I2:I278")
        strConcat = strConcat & rngCell & rngCell.Offset(0, -7) & "||"
    Next rngCell

    arrConcat = Split(strConcat, "||")

    For Each rngCell In Display.Range("D3:F23")
        If rngCell.Value >= 0 Then
            strConsolidated = Right(Display.Cells(rngCell.Row, 1).Value, 1)
            strPERSON = Display.Cells(1, rngCell.Column).Value
            For lngPos = 0 To UBound(arrConcat)
                If LCase$(strConsolidated & strPERSON) = LCase$(arrConcat(lngPos)) Then
                    With WIPDATA
                        strComment = strComment & Chr(10) _
                            & "W/O " & .Range("B" & lngPos + 2).Value & Chr(10) _
                            & "OP# " & .Range("F" & lngPos + 2).Value & Chr(10) _
                            & "Qty " & .Range("I" & lngPos + 2).Value
                    End With
                End If
            Next lngPos
            rngCell.ClearComments
            If Len(strComment) > 0 Then
                rngCell.AddComment (Right(strComment, Len(strComment) - 1))
                rngCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
            End If
            strComment = vbNullString
        End If
    Next rngCell
     End Sub
```

If it goes right, Notes are added to each cell in the range with corresponding data from the following sheet.

This is solved: Get a

> Run-time error '424' Object Required

And it takes me to line 5. `For Each rngCell In WIPDATA.Range("I2:I278")`

Now I get notes applied to "E" and "F" But they aren't grabbing any values from the second sheet. Pictures updated to show latest.

Please Keep in mind that I'm mainly adapting already written code. Still very much learning and teaching myself at that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which line does it stop at when the error occurs?

Comment: Line 5. Editing Post to inform.

Comment: What is `WIPDATA`? I have no idea. VBA seems to have no idea either. Please provide a [mcve]. Perhaps replace `WIPDATA` by `Sheets("WIPDATA")`.

Comment: Just the name of the second sheet.

Comment: Is that the codename of the second sheet though?

Comment: Think you're missing setting the worksheet to a variable. first declare the Variable, then set it. Like this `Dim WIPDATA As Worksheet` then `Set WIPDATA = Worksheets("WIPDATA")`. Will also need to be done for Display. Its a very good idea to add `Option Explicit` before all the code in any modules, which will force you to declare variables, will catch typos, and help debug code.

Comment: Should be. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAdHL.png

Comment: That apparently was critical. Now it runs with no error, but the result gives me no saved notes in any cells.

Comment: Also a good idea to clean up afterward... I.e. `Set MyObject = Nothing`.       To automatically do `Option Explicit` in all your modules, in the VBA window > Tools > Options > Editor > Tick "Require Variable Declaration". (Actually I have everything on that list ticked). [Set-statement on microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement)

Comment: @gomugomuking sheet name is not the same as code name: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNdw7.png

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before adding them. I've removed the [tag:excel-vba] you added, as the first sentence of the description says **THIS TAG IS PENDING REMOVAL**, which clearly indicates it should not be used on new posts.

Comment: When setting objects it is helpful to use a simple error check to make sure they are set before continuing in your code. Something like `If WIPDATA Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` after setting this object could help in future developments.

Comment: If Len(strComment) Then   - If the length of strcomment what? I think you mean  If Len(strComment) >0 then

Comment: Updated. I am not confident in Line 10. Can I rely on an Offset instruction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I was able to recreate your dataset properly. Assuming that you want to match `Display` sheet, Person (row 2) & Consolidated number (column C), with `WIPDATA`, Person (column A) & Consolidated number (column P), then you would need to use the following code:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim strComment As String, strConsolidated As String, strPERSON As String, strConcat As String
    Dim arrConcat() As String
    Dim lngPos As Long

    Dim WIPDATA As Worksheet
    Dim Display As Worksheet
    Set WIPDATA = Worksheets("WIPDATA")
    Set Display = Worksheets("Display")

    For Each rngCell In WIPDATA.Range("A2:A278")
        strConcat = strConcat & rngCell.Offset(0, 15) & rngCell & "||"
    Next rngCell

    arrConcat = Split(strConcat, "||")

    For Each rngCell In Display.Range("D3:F23")
        If rngCell.Value >= 0 Then
            strConsolidated = Display.Cells(rngCell.Row, 3).Value
            strPERSON = Display.Cells(2, rngCell.Column).Value
            For lngPos = 0 To UBound(arrConcat)
                If LCase$(strConsolidated & strPERSON) = LCase$(arrConcat(lngPos)) Then
                    With WIPDATA
                        strComment = strComment & Chr(10) _
                            & "W/O " & .Range("B" & lngPos + 2).Value & Chr(10) _
                            & "OP# " & .Range("F" & lngPos + 2).Value & Chr(10) _
                            & "Qty " & .Range("I" & lngPos + 2).Value
                    End With
                End If
            Next lngPos
            rngCell.ClearComments
            If Len(strComment) Then
                rngCell.AddComment (Right(strComment, Len(strComment) - 1))
                rngCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
            End If
            strComment = vbNullString
        End If
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

`Display` sheet on my side displays two comments (yellow & orange colours):

[image]

`WIPDATA` setup (sorry, I was being lazy and I only copied part of your table!):

[image]

I created only 3 scenarios where Person & Consolidated match between both sheets, but hopefully you will be able to see that yellow & orange coloured rows are properly being copied into `Display` sheet comments.

Give it a try and let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Changes worked. But I don't understand why. This line confuses me:
strConcat = strConcat & rngCell.Offset(0, 15) & rngCell & "||"

Comment: This line is creating a very long string - it concatenates "Consolidated" (cell A2 + offset 15 columns = cell P2) with "Person" (cell A2), adds "||" delimiter, then concatenates P3 and A3, adds "||" delimiter, then concatenates P4 and A4... and so on. After it is finished, `strConcat` will look somewhat like that -> `1300Bob||1300Bob||1400Gary||1400Bob||...` Afterwards we have a line `arrConcat = Split(strConcat, "||")` which splits this huge string into an Array using `||` delimiter. It will be then used in `For lngPos = 0 To UBound(arrConcat)` loop. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Ok so that's all the matchwork. Thank you. Now when it comes to line 15 strConsolidated = Display.Cells(rngCell.Row, 3).Value this sets the strin for Column C, and should be able to be moved to say Column U, by :
strConsolidated = Display.Cells(rngCell.Row, 21).Value